# Use ClosedXML to show exponent value with use of superscript

Tags: exponent, closedxml

With ClosedXML, I need to show 10 (base) with a superscript of 2.
As such it is an exponent value. I know I can do a subscript of 2 the following way:

```
            ws.Cell(2, 8).Value = 2;            
            ws.Cell(2, 8).Style.Font.VerticalAlignment =  XLFontVerticalTextAlignmentValues.Superscript;
```

But how do I show 10 which is a base in the same cell as the superscript value?
Essentially I am trying to show 2 different styles of font in the same cell. 
Hopefully this makes sense.

I tried to use the following but did not get far as it show 102 instead of 2 as a superscript:

```
 ws.Cell(2, 8).Value = 102; 
 ws.Cell(rw, 8).RichText.Substring(2).VerticalAlignment = XLFontVerticalTextAlignmentValues.Superscript;
```

Answer (score 2):

That seems to be a problem with Excel itself. In Excel I could not set the `2` to superscript if the content of the cell is a number. After changing the content to `'102` to force it to be text, it worked.

And the same works in ClosedXML:

```
ws.Cell(2, 8).Value = "'102";
ws.Cell(rw, 8).RichText.Substring(2).VerticalAlignment = XLFontVerticalTextAlignmentValues.Superscript;
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the previous answer is no longer valid. The interface for adding rich text to cells in ClosedXML has changed (since version 0.100, I believe).

You can use the method [`IXLCell.CreateRichText`](https://docs.closedxml.io/en/0.100.0/api/cell.html#function-ClosedXML.Excel.IXLCell.CreateRichText) to replace the value of the cell by a rich text object. This method returns the rich text object allowing you to chain methods to it as follows:

```
// Method 1: Add rich text by chaining methods
ws.Cell("A1").CreateRichText()
    .AddText("Some Red Text").SetFontColor(XLColor.Red)
    .AddText("with superscript").SetVerticalAlignment(XLFontVerticalTextAlignmentValues.Superscript)
    .AddText("and some bold and italic").SetBold().SetItalic()
    ;
```

The second way of doing this is by calling the same method on a cell, then using [`IXLCell.GetRichText`](https://docs.closedxml.io/en/0.100.0/api/cell.html#function-ClosedXML.Excel.IXLCell.GetRichText) to get the rich text object. This allows for more flexibility in dynamic styling.

In the following code we format the text as Subscript if the associated color is 'Bole'.

```
// List of (text, color)-tuples for demonstration
var textColorTuples = new List<(string, XLColor)>{
    ("Aqua ", XLColor.Aqua),
    ("CarminePink ", XLColor.CarminePink),
    ("Bole ", XLColor.Bole),
    ("PinkOrange ", XLColor.PinkOrange),
};

// Method 2: Add rich text object to cell, then later
var cell = ws.Cell("A2");
cell.CreateRichText();
foreach((var text, var color) in textColorTuples){
    if (color == XLColor.Bole){ // Styling rich text conditionally
        cell.GetRichText().AddText(text).SetFontColor(color).SetBold().SetVerticalAlignment(XLFontVerticalTextAlignmentValues.Subscript);
    }
    else{
        cell.GetRichText().AddText(text).SetFontColor(color).SetBold();
    }
}
```

This code creates the following excel sheet:
[image]